# retrieve the hidden default.aspx segment of a url

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I tried to display the url using all sorts of methods of HttpRequest, I tried VirtualPathUtility object as well, but I never was able to display the hidden portion "default.aspx" of the default... what is the method or property that retrieves this segment of the url?

reason being, I am so close to creating a 404 on application level that catches all 404s, even html pages, by using File.Exist() on the mapped path of the url, unfortunately, that does not work on the default page.

I have seen few articles trying to do the opposite, remove default.aspx when it occurs, this is not the case here.

Edit: here is what I am trying:

```
string fullOrigionalpath = context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.ToString();
bool newUrl = System.IO.File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath(fullOrigionalpath));
if (!newUrl) throw new HttpException(404,"page not found");
```

now you see, if the page is **localhost/lexus/default.aspx**, it works fine with no errors, but if I type in the address **http://localhost/lexus/**, the error is thrown, because if you try to output the fullOriginalPath, it does not have "default.aspx" part of it, so Exists returns false! do you have a better way of checking for validity of physical files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is at all possible, so I relied on IIS7.0 rewrite feature to force the default.aspx to appear at all times..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hidden portion" but have you tried ...

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ye be looking for the `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` Property on the `HttpRequest` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath.aspx

If someone makes a request to http://yourdomain.com/ the value of `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` would be `"~/default.aspx"`

Comment: that didnt work either :( it returns ~/, and when checking for File.Exists, it returns false! is there an IIS setting im missing?

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, what you want is the ability to get the Physical File Path for the requested file? Where the Requested URL could be something like "http://mydomain.com/" and you would expect the result to be "~/default.aspx"?